# Rstan Error: Cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, rstan

I'm following the blog post here (https://mattocci27.github.io/assets/poilog_mix/poilog_mix.html) exactly, but keep running into a strange error. To be totally precise, I am running:

```
library(rstan)

mu <- c(log(50), log(400))
sigma <- c(0.8, 0.2)
theta <- 0.8

N <- 100
z <- rbinom(N, 1, 1 - theta) + 1
log_lambda <- rnorm(N, mu[z], sigma[z])
Y <- rpois(N, exp(log_lambda))

rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE)
options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())

list_dat <- list(N = N, y = Y)

fit_cp <- stan(file = "poilog_mix_cp.stan",
            data = list_dat,
            iter = 2000,
            warmup = 1000,
            thin = 1,
            chains =  4,
            refresh = 500,
            control = list(adapt_delta = 0.9, max_treedepth = 20))
```

with the file "poilog_mix_cp.stan" as follows:

```
data{
  int<lower=0> N;
  int y[N];
}

parameters {
   ordered[2] mu;
   real<lower=0> sigma[2];
   real<lower=0, upper=1> theta;
   vector[N] log_lambda[2];
}

model {
  sigma ~ cauchy(0, 2.5);
  mu ~ normal(0, 10);
  theta ~ beta(2, 2);
  for (i in 1:2)
   log_lambda[i,] ~ normal(mu[i], sigma[i]);
  for (n in 1:N)
   target += log_mix(theta,
                     poisson_log_lpmf(y[n] | log_lambda[1, n]),
                     poisson_log_lpmf(y[n] | log_lambda[2, n]));
}
```

but at the step of fitting the model, I get the following error:

```
Error in as.character(sys.call(sys.parent())[[1L]]) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

I'm not sure what's going on, since I'm just copying the blog post.

Comment: I am not getting this error. Are you using the version of **rstan** currently on CRAN?

Comment: Yes, I am. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, with no dice.

Comment: Do any Stan models run on that machine? Like `example(stan_model, run.dontrun = TRUE)`?

Comment: I ended up figuring out that if I use R version 3.5, everything is fine, and I only have trouble with version 3.6. So, I'm downgrading to 3.5 for now. Thank you for the help, though!